# How to deserialize some field of a complex JSON in RUST

Tags: json, rust, json-deserialization

I want to extract some information about my json string but I have some issue when I try to do it.

This is the style of my string in json format:

```
{
    "id": "my_id",
    "field1": {
        "value": true,
        "test": true
    },
    "target": {
        "value1": "value",
        "value2": 0,
        "value3": true,
        "test": false
    },
    "field2": [
        "value"
    ],
    "files": [
        "this/is/my/path"
    ]
}
{
    "id": "my_id",
    "field1": {
        "value": true,
        "test": true
    },
    "target": {
        "value1": "value",
        "value2": 30,
        "value3": false,
        "test": false
    },
    "field2": [
        "value"
    ],
    "files": [
        "this/is/my/path"
    ]
}
{
    "id": "my_id",
    "field1": {
        "value": true,
        "test": true
    },
    "target": {
        "value1": "value",
        "value2": 10,
        "value3": true,
        "test": true
    },
    "field2": [
        "value"
    ],
    "files": [
        "this/is/my/path"
    ]
}
```

for each object, I'd like to extract the test field in target and files path.

To do that I try:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct AllFiles {
    target: Target,
    files: Vec<String>
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Target {
    test: bool
}

fn main() {
   let json = "JSON string above ^^^";
   let all_files: Vec<AllFiles> = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
}
```

but I have this error: `Error("invalid type: map, expected a sequence", line: 1, column: 0)'`

I can't figure out how to manage it.
At the end I want Vec so I can browse it and test each of its objects

can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What's `Vect`? A typo? Also this is not a valid JSON string, you can only have one object at the root.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59a57292b8dfa1d83bec67aa1f5c2321). That being said, your data is a bit weird. You have commas on top level, that's not actually valid JSON as is, you need some extra `[` `]` around that string. If you just want to deserialize one `AllFiles`, lose the `Vec` around it in `main`.

Comment: @cafce25 yes sorry both are typos.

Comment: @Caesar yes sorry it was a typo, I correct it. There is no comma.

Comment: @Yogi this is what I get from the output of a program with the --message-format=json option

Comment: Is the original data in [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format or something?

Comment: @kmdreko I don't know but it looks like it, I didn't know. I'll take a look thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data, as it's currently in your post, contains multiple JSON values. To parse, you'll need a `serde_json::StreamDeserializer`, which you can construct with `serde_json::Deserializer::into_iter`:

```
let all_files = serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(json)
    .into_iter()
    .collect::<Result<Vec<AllFiles>, _>>();
```

The details are in the [`serde_json` docs](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/struct.StreamDeserializer.html).

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb9ed421643580fe5e9d7efb003dac4f)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your issue on the Rust Playground, ans this code runs correctly. I'm assuming your data is contained inside an array, and I've also changed the path strings to contain a number at the end for the purposes of better visualization of the results. You can try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a627697a8a2ca5801f59b26447b48791)

```rs
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct AllFiles {
    target: Target,
    files: Vec<String>
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Target {
    test: bool
}

fn main() {
   let json = r#"[
   {
        "id": "my_id",
        "field1": {
            "value": true,
            "test": true
        },
        "target": {
            "value1": "value",
            "value2": 0,
            "value3": true,
            "test": false
        },
        "field2": [
            "value"
        ],
        "files": [
            "this/is/my/path1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "my_id",
        "field1": {
            "value": true,
            "test": true
        },
        "target": {
            "value1": "value",
            "value2": 0,
            "value3": true,
            "test": false
        },
        "field2": [
            "value"
        ],
        "files": [
            "this/is/my/path2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "my_id",
        "field1": {
            "value": true,
            "test": true
        },
        "target": {
            "value1": "value",
            "value2": 10,
            "value3": true,
            "test": true
        },
        "field2": [
            "value"
        ],
        "files": [
            "this/is/my/path3"
        ]
    }
    ]"#;
   let all_files: Vec<AllFiles> = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
   
   for item in all_files {
       println!("{:?}", item);
   }
}
```